# Salvar arquivo PDF no temp do PHP

Tags: php, mpdf, fpdf

Existe alguma classe, como a mPDF ou fPDF, que consiga mandar seu saída pra um arquivo temporário, ou algo do tipo, para ser enviado via e-mail no mesmo?

A demanda é a seguinte: preciso que o e-mail seja anexado automaticamente, sem o cara selecionar arquivos.

Algum caminho das pedras?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, conseguiu usar a resposta? Falta algo?

Comment: Na verdade, mudei de empresa até

Comment: Mas na época chegou a testar? Pense que a sua duvida pode ser a duvida de futuros visitantes do site.

Comment: Não, a demanda passou pra outra pessoa que não sei

Comment: Sai da empresa muuuito rapidamente

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o *stream* chamado [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

---

### Usando MPDF

Se estiver usando o MPDF (versão 7) provavelmente usa o composer para instalar, então deve ficar assim:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Então um exemplo com mpdf:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Stack Overflow');

$mpdf->Output('php://temp', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```

E no Phpmailer use assim:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  //Configure o seu SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // usuario
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // senha
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // TLS se tiver criptografia
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    //Porta do SMTP

    //Destinatários
    $mail->setFrom('guilherme@pt.stackoverflow.com');

    //ADICIONA O ANEXO AQUI
    $mail->addAttachment('php://temp', 'Arquivo.pdf'); 

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'ASSUNTO';
    $mail->Body    = 'Mensagem';
    $mail->AltBody = 'mensagem para clientes de email que não usam HTML';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Mensagem enviada';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

---

### Usando FPDF

Se não estiver usando composer e estiver usando FPDF primeiro importe o que é necessário:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'path/to/fpdf.php';
```

Depois chame o FDPF:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial',  'B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Stack Overflow!');
$pdf->Output('F', 'php://temp');
```

E no phpmailer é igual ao primeiro exemplo, se mantem assim:

```
//ADICIONA O ANEXO AQUI
$mail->addAttachment('php://temp', 'Arquivo.pdf');
```